# Update specific column in grid view from button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How to update ASP.Net Gridview column with all rows acording to curent data...

somethings like , column name is Issue Mode with 2 rows like `N and F` .. when i need to change data as,

```
if value is "F" set the value to "CF" or

if value is "N" set the value to CN
```

Visual example:

[image]

Comment: you need to loop over `GirdView.Rows` then each `Row.Cells`. Check the `Cell.Header`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **RowDataBound** event like following:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
        if(e.Row.Cells[0].Text =="F")
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "CF";
        }
        else if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text == "N")
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "CN";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ( GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
   if(row.Cells[0].Text=="F")
   {
       row.Cells[0].Text ="CF";
   }
   else if(row.Cells[0].Text=="N")
   {
       row.Cells[0].Text ="CN";
   }
}
```

Comment: in this case how to fined the specific column ...

                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Issue Mode">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IssueMode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("IssueMode") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>

Answer (score 1):

On button Click Try this..

```
foreach ( DataRow dr in GridView1.Rows)    
{
    dr["columnname"].Value = "abcd";    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ( GridViewRow rw in GridView1.Rows)
{
if (rw.Cell[0].Text =="F")
{
        rw.Cells[0].Text ="CF";
}
else if (rw.Cells[1].Text =="N")
{
       rw.Cells[1].Text ="CN";
}
}
```